# Joomla - setting field attribute in a plugin

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I created a user plugin for extending default user profile in Joomla 3.6.5.
I added the following field **sample_title** in **profiles/profile.xml**.

```
<field
    name="sample_title"
    type="list"
    id="sample_title" description="sample description..." label="sample title"  default="">
    <option value="mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>                
</field>
```

in my plugin class I have a **function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)**. In this function I try to change the required attribute of the sample_title by doing **$form->setFieldAttribute('sample_title', 'required', 'true', 'profilecustom');**
If i see the required attribute value on the next line it seems it is ok the required is "true".This code **echo $form->getFieldAttribute('sample_title', 'required', 'false', 'profilecustom');** prints true which is OK for me.
BUT when I display the registration view (I use the **registration/default.php** view from com_users) the sample_title field is declared as optional. In the registration view, we have

```
<?php if (!$field->required && $field->type != 'Spacer') : ?>
    <span class="optional"><?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_OPTIONAL');?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this span is displayed for sample_title while I set the required field attribute to true so it is not OK...

As additional information:

- I tried **$form->setFieldAttribute('sample_title', 'required', 'true', 'profilecustom');** and **$form->setFieldAttribute('sample_title', 'required', true, 'profilecustom');**. The result is the same.
- I followed the following documentation (https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) to create my plugin.

Am I doing something wrong?
I know that I can put the required value in the field declaration

```
<field
    name="sample_title"
    type="list"
    id="sample_title" description="sample description..." label="sample_title"  default="" required="true">
```

but this is not what I want. I want to set this value under some conditions so I need to do it programmatically.

---

I continued my investigation :-) In the registration view, if I use the default way to display the fields

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field) : ?> 
....
<?php if (!$field->required && $field->type != 'Spacer') : ?>
<span class="optional"><?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_OPTIONAL');?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
...
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**$field->required** is false but if I try to get the field with **$sample_title_field = $this->form->getField('sample_title', 'profilecustom');** then **$sample_title_field->required** is true so It seems there is some inconsistency between the fields returned by **$this->form->getFieldset($fieldset->name);** and those those get with **$this->form->getField(...);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code (https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin), they do **$form->loadFile('profile', false);**. I replaced this code by **$form->loadFile('profile', true);** and now the field attributes are correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I use **$form->loadFile('profile');**, it works too.